# How do I get a property of non object in php?

Tags: php

This is the array:

```
$response = array( 'message-count' => '1', 'messages' => array ( 0 => array ( 'to' => '12345667888', 'message-id' => 'XXXXXXXXXXX', 'status' => '0', 'remaining-balance' => '9.26820000', 'message-price' => '0.03330000', 'network' => '11111', ), ), );
```

What code do I use to get like, for example, the 'message-id' 's data?

I've tried $response->messages["message-id"];
but what I get is Trying to get property 'messages' of non-object
Tried a lot of others as well they are all returning the same error

I am quite new to this so I hope I could get some help here

Sorry:
Vardump gives me this, made a mistake with the code above

```
'{
    "message-count": "1",
    "messages": [{
        "to": "12345667888",
        "message-id": "XXXXXXXXXXX",
        "status": "0",
        "remaining-balance": "9.20160000",
        "message-price": "0.03330000",
        "network": "11111"
    }]
}'
```

Comment: As it's an array you need to use array notation - `$response["messages"][0]["message-id"]`

Comment: `response` is an array already so you need the access syntax: `response["messages"][0]["message-id"]`. On my phone now if you want I can give a more in depth answer tomorrow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

response is an array, you can't get `messages` like -> , You should get `message-id` by this way:

```
$jsonStr = '{
    "message-count": "1",
    "messages": [{
        "to": "12345667888",
        "message-id": "XXXXXXXXXXX",
        "status": "0",
        "remaining-balance": "9.20160000",
        "message-price": "0.03330000",
        "network": "11111"
    }]
}';

$data = json_decode($jsonStr);

$messageId = $data->messages[0]->{'message-id'};

echo $messageId; //or var_dump($messageId)
```

Comment: Sorry, i copied the wrong var dump, how about the edited one?

Answer (score 1):

Your array contains non-object values so you can retrieve the values as below.

```
<?php

$response = array('message-count' => '1', 'messages' => array(0 => array('to' => '12345667888', 'message-id' => 'XXXXXXXXXXX', 'status' => '0', 'remaining-balance' => '9.26820000', 'message-price' => '0.03330000', 'network' => '11111',),),);

echo $response['messages'][0]['message-id'];

// Output 
// XXXXXXXXXXX
```

Comment: Sorry, i copied the wrong var dump, how about the edited one?

Comment: The same answer is applicable for that

Comment: Thanks, but I am not getting  Illegal string offset 'messages' error :/ Do you know what might be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I would use `array_column` function like this

```
array_column($response['messages'], 'message-id');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$msg = '{
    "message-count": "1",
    "messages": [{
        "to": "12345667888",
        "message-id": "XXXXXXXXXXX",
        "status": "0",
        "remaining-balance": "9.20160000",
        "message-price": "0.03330000",
        "network": "11111"
    }]
}';

$data = json_decode($msg);

$messageId = $data->messages[0]->{'message-id'};

var_dump($messageId);
```

If you have more than one message in the list then,

```
$messages = $data->messages;
foreach ($messages as $index => $message) {
    var_dump($message); // whole message detail
    var_dump($message->{'message-id'});// message-id
}
```